# VB.NET Linq Expression with function(x) is not executed?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Why is this working as expected:

```
list.ForEach(sub(x) x.Name = "New Name")
```

But this isn't:

```
list.ForEach(function(x) x.Name = "New Name")
```

Anyone else confused?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating a problem. State your expectations, and what *actually* happened.

Comment: Refer to this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67916/lambda-expressions-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List(Of T).ForEach takes as an argument an Action (Sub) that doesn't return a value not a Func (Function) that does return a value.

In VB the = sign is ambiguous. It can either be used for comparison or assignment. As a result to disambiguate the statement, `x.Name = "New Name"` the team used the indicator Sub or Function to identify if this is a comparison or assignment. In the case of `Sub(x) x.Name = "New Name"`, you are performing an assignment, or set the value of x's Name parameter to "New Name". In the case of `Function(x) x.Name = New "Name"` you are doing a comparison and returning if the Name parameter of x  is the same as "New Name". As a result, you have to be careful when you use Sub and Function.

Answer (score 6):

When you are using the `Function` keyword

```
list.ForEach(Function(x) x.Name = "New Name")
```

you are creating a function that takes an argument named `x` and returns a `bool` (in this case).

So, in this case, `=` is not the assignment operator, but the comparison operator, hence the `Name` property is not changed. 
(The compiler infers that the function returns a `bool` due to the comparison operator)

It's equivalent to

```
list.ForEach(sub(x) Foobar(x))

...

Function Foobar(x as Foo) As Boolean
    Return x.Name = "New Name" 'returns a boolean'
End Function
```

Comment: Your foobar function does not specify a return value